# Creating a jsPDF-Autotable with fixed column widths determining table width

Tags: jspdf-autotable

I need to present a table transposed from the usual manner data is presented (i.e. in the table required, each record is represented by a column, and each field is represented by a row).

I would like each column aside from the 1st (header column) to have the same width.

Overflowing columns will be in a new table sitting below the table above (see below).

For the final table (which will usually have a different number of columns to the table sitting above it), the width of the columns should be the same.

Therefore in the .PDF generated by the snippet below, the 2 tables should align as so (*noting the exact number of cells will differ*):

```
+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|Day  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  | 9  | 10 |
+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
+-----+----+----+----+----+
|Day  | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
+-----+----+----+----+----+
```

```js
// generating the data for the table
const cols = 14;
const headers = (new Array(cols + 1)).fill(0).map((x,i) => (i).toString());
headers[0] = 'DAY #:';
const today = new Date();
const data = [headers.map((x, i) => {
    const date = new Date(today);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + i);
    return date.toLocaleDateString(navigator.languages);
  }),
  headers.map((x, i) => (1 - i / cols).toPrecision(3)),
];
data[0][0] = "Date:"
data[1][0] = "Dose:"

// splitting the table data at 10 columns + rowHeader wide
const maxCols = 10;
const tables = [];
const tableCount = Math.ceil(cols/maxCols)
for (let i = 0; i < tableCount; ++i) {
  const slicePos = 1 + i * maxCols;
  const mapColsInRange = (d) => [d[0]].concat(d.slice(slicePos, slicePos + maxCols));
  tables.push({
    headers: mapColsInRange(headers),
    data: data.map(mapColsInRange),
  });
}
// creating the tables
const doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4');
for (const t of tables) {
  doc.autoTable({
    theme: 'grid',
    head: [ t.headers ],
    body: t.data,
    pageBreak: 'avoid',
    styles: { halign: 'center', cellWidth: 21 },
    columnStyles: { 0: { halign: 'left', fontStyle: 'bold', cellWidth: 34 }},
  });
}
doc.save('test.pdf');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/3.1.4/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js"></script>
```

How can the columns be aligned using jsPDF-autoTable options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

adding the autotable option `tableWidth: 'wrap'` was the solution

Answer (score 1):

```
const printableColumns = ['Account ID', 'First name', 'Last name', 'Created'];
```

If you want to change the width of 'Last name' than put the column index number instead of dataKey in 'columnStyles' and set the cellWidth

```
doc.autoTable({
        head: [printableColumns],
        body: pdfData,            ,
        columnStyles: {
            2: {cellWidth: 30},                           
        }            
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the columns to be fixed width using `cellWidth` option.

Comment: Thank you for answering - unfortunately it is not working in the snippet with the question, which sets the cellwidth in both the styles & in the columnStyles { 0. I have also tried setting the cellWidth for each columnStyle [1...10], with the same outcome

Comment: There is in example showing how to use the cellWidth style in examples/examples.js in the repo. Quite similar to what you want to achieve I think!